# react-d3-graph distribute nodes without links

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, nodes, react-d3-graph

I'm using [`react-d3-graph`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-graph) for adding several nodes **with** and **without** links.

When I'm adding several nodes **without a link**, they are all in the top left corner, which means that they are always above each other.

Is there any config I can set to auto spread them on the graph?

---

#### Here is an example of that case:

[CodeSanbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-2e5qit?file=/src/App.js)

The data:

```js
const data = {
  nodes: [
    {
      id: "node-1",
      fx: 100,
      fy: 100
    },
    {
      id: "node-2",
      fx: 200,
      fy: 200
    },
    {
      id: "node-3",
      fx: 300,
      fy: 300
    },
    {
      id: "node-4",
      fx: 300,
      fy: 300
    }
  ],
  links: [
    {
      source: "node-1",
      target: "node-2"
    }
  ]
};
```

And you can see the `node-1` and `node-2` are connected, so they are aligned correctly, but `node-3` and `node-4` are not connected, so they are overlapping on the top-left point.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same issue

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = {
      nodes: [
        {
          "id": "VUX",
          "symbolType": "square"
        },
        {
          "id": "Guardian",
          "symbolType": "square"
        },
        {
          "id": "Broodhmome",
          "symbolType": "square"
        },
        {
          "id": "Avenger",
          "symbolType": "square"
        },
        {
          "id": "Podship",
          "symbolType": "square"
        },
        {
          "id": "Eluder",
          "symbolType": "square"
        },
        {
          "id": "Drone",
          "symbolType": "square"
        },
        {
          "id": "Intruder",
          "symbolType": "square"
        },
      ],
      links: [
        {
          "source": "VUX",
          "target": "Intruder"
        }
      ],
    };

    const config = {
      width: 2000,
      height: 2000,
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Graph id="my-graph" data={data} config={config} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image]

It should render like this but it is not

If you have found a solution please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to this [example I created](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/currying-smoke-7dw9q7?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A22%2C30&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqweqkp0006356iijo4znuq%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqweqko0002356icct58xr3%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqweqko0003356irxw19gdb%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqweqko0005356iwkbchfhk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B58.644174952583484%252C41.355825047416516%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltqweqko0002356icct58xr3%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqweqko0002356icct58xr3%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A22%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A30%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A22%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A30%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqx1c3p00la356i2c5d0toe%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522src%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A19%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A19%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A30%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A30%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltr80enn006n356iyb4nu7hi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltqx1c3p00la356i2c5d0toe%2522%257D%252C%2522cltqweqko0005356iwkbchfhk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqweqko0004356iq7f0dd3r%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqweqko0005356iwkbchfhk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltqweqko0004356iq7f0dd3r%2522%257D%252C%2522cltqweqko0003356irxw19gdb%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltqweqko0003356irxw19gdb%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).

Note 1: I used the trick by adding the cyrcle link to the unlinked nodes. While direction arrow is need not to be displayed - it is Ok, otherwise...

Note 2: the Graph should be initiated with the empty object. And receive the real data after small delay.

Note 3: pay attention to the used configuration.